# Solace mqtt connection failure logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, solace

May I know where can I find logs of failed connection attempts to Solace PubSub+ Software Message Broker?
I have deployed the broker to AWS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do note that only under certain connection failure scenarios will logs be generated on the Broker.

Nevertheless, here are the steps to access the logs on a Software Event Broker.

a. Access the Solace Application Shell

```
[sysadmin@solace ~]$ solacectl shell
```

b. Navigate to the logs directory

```
[appuser@solace ~]$ cd logs/
```

Relevant log entries for the Software Event Broker can then be found in the event, system and command log files.

Here is a breakdown of what is contained in each log file:

a. Command log: Information about Solace PubSub+ event broker commands issued by users

b. Event log: System-wide events, Message VPN events, local publisher, subscriber and client events

c. System log: Subset of the Solace PubSub+ event broker event logs

If necessary, you may refer to https://docs.solace.com/Solace-PubSub-Event-Reference/PubSub-Event-Reference.htm under "Event Reference" for all possible events that can be generated on a Solace PubSub+ event broker.

Comment: Thanks Dedrick. After getting to the logs folder, we can use "tail -f event.log | grep CLIENT:" to see live streams of client connections to the broker.